# Why $-reference possible to Perl array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I am thinking how you can refer to an element in Perl array by the sign `$`.

Minimum code

```
my @x = @{ $_[0] }; 

for(my $i=0; $i<$#x; $i++){
    print $x[$i]; 
}
```

You initialize the array as `@x` that is an array. 
You print out each item from the array by `$x[$i]` in a for loop.

I think it is a bit confusing when you initialize the array by `@x` and get its size by `$#x`.

Why can you refer to the Perl array by `$x`?

Comment: ***`$#x`*** is ***NOT*** the size of the array. It is the index of the last element of the array. The size of the array is `@x` evaluated in scalar context. Also, `my $x = shift; print $x->[$_] for 0 .. $#$x;` to print the elements of the array without creating a copy.

Comment: @SinanÜnür So the index can be something else than scalar in Perl. Right?

Comment: Indexing imposes scalar context. When you write `$ary[ ... ]` whatever is between `[ ]` is evaluated in scalar context. For example, `$ary[ @ary ]` will ***always*** be `undef` thanks to autovivification. In C, it would access an out-of-bounds memory location and lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @SinanÜnür So `$#x` should correspond to the size of the array through the last element of the array. Any cases where gaps in numbering? Possible?

Comment: `$#x` is the last index --- ***NOT THE SIZE OF THE ARRAY***. I don't know how much clearer this can be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the perlish way is to have the sigil denoting the type of thing you're working with, rather than being part of the variable name.

`$x` is a scalar, unrelated to the list `@x`. 
However `$x[1]` is *still* a scalar - but it's an element *from* the list `@x`. (and is unrelated to `$x`, because clearly - you couldn't pick a single element out of a single element).

`$#x` is a single value (scalar) so has the `$` prefix still.

The same applies to hashes. `%hash` is the whole hash. `$hash{$key}` is a single value from that hash. And `@hash{@some_keys}` is a list of values from that hash.

Answer (score 1):

You're not referring to the array with `$x`, you're referring to an *element* of the array with it.  Your array is an array of *scalar* values which you use `$` to access.

Please see the [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) and [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) documentation.  It'll cover the "why" of your question.